# Return several layers from listwidget

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, qt-designer

I am new to python and I am writing my first plugin that add selected layers from a listwidget to QGIS.
So good so far, but it does not allow me to select several layers at once. Am I missing something in my code for that option?

```
 def run(self):
    # First clear the list widget
      self.dlg.listWidget.clear()

    # Fill the list
      f = codecs.open("C:/temp/testlist.txt", 'r', 'utf-8')
      for line in f: # Repeat for every line in the list file
        fileData = line.strip() # Remove any new line characters from the line (strip)
        if fileData != "": # Ignore empty lines
            if fileData[:1] != "#": # Ignore lines that start with hasch-tag
              tempList = fileData.split(",") # Separate the line by comma signs and put it in a temporary list
              layerProvider.append( tempList[0] ) # Add the first item to the layerProvider list
              layerName.append( tempList[1] ) # Add the second item to the layerName list
              layerSource.append( tempList[2] ) # Add the third item to the layerSource list
              self.dlg.listWidget.addItem(tempList[1]) # Add the Name of the layer to the list widget.

      f.close() 

    # show the dialog
      self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
      result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
      if result == 1:
            # do something useful (delete the line containing pass and
            # substitute with your code)
           selectedLayers = self.dlg.listWidget.selectedItems()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the selection behaviour of the listwidget using it's setSelectionMode() method. A description of the different modes is given in the
[QAbstractItemView Reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionMode-enum). In your case something like

```
self.dlg.listWidget.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
```

should do the trick (but I didn't test it).

Comment: Thanks for your input! I put it in after self.dlg.listWidget.clear() and it threw me global name 'QAbstractItemView' is not defined. I will digg into it and let you know if it work!!

Comment: Oh sorry, you have of course to import the QAbstractItemView class at first. Insert `from PyQt4.QtGui import QAbstractItemView` at the top of your page to overcome the issue :)

Comment: Ah yes thank you! I changed it in the Qt Designer. In the property editor is the SelectionMode that I changed to MultiSelection